# Is it okay to collect geoip/country data with an online job form?

Tags: discrimination

Recently we added a few job adverts to our company website. In the form 'please apply' the applicant can enter their name, a cover letter, tick the box to say they can work in the country and upload their CV.

As well as the form elements that the applicant sees we also submit a few extra things for improving how our website works - including IP address, time spent filling in the form and the country of the applicant, as worked out from the IP address.

As it happens these extra fields - which were just for the IT department - are used by the HR department. They do like to see whether the application was agonised over, what the referer link was and so on. However, I am concerned that having the applicant's country on the form could be seen as wrong, even discriminatory. If someone applies from somewhere far away then we could look at the country field and just go no further, application 'deleted as spam'.

Could we get into any legal problems for a) collecting a job applicant's guestimated country and b) putting that information with their cover letter to be read by the HR department?

Comment: Yes, you could get in trouble. You should update your form and/or website to tell what data is collected and how it's going to be used, and "That by using our web site, you agree to such and such" with an checkbox to tick.

Comment: any question that asks about something being legal has to include your country.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt - even then it might not be legal to use that information in order to differentiate between different candidates. The safest choice would be to restrict HR's access to any information which they can't ask for legally.

Comment: @AndreiROM good point.

Comment: You might want to discuss the accuracy of the data with HR. What may be useful in aggregate can be very misleading if you try to apply it to an individual.  They can't tell whether someone got a call in the middle of filling out the application and walked away from it for an hour or whether they 'agonized' over it.

Comment: Are you in US?  If not,  please specify the country.

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate which information HR should not have access to - by law - and inform management that you recommend immediately restricting HR's access to that information (for the good of the company). Be sure to point out that giving this info to HR and then simply trusting them not to "use it" still leaves the company open to potential lawsuits.

Explicitly informing applicants that certain information is being collected may, or may not, be legally required at that point, as I'm assuming that there is an implied EULA to them using your job application system anyway (if not, your company should implement one, and you can recommend this as well).

HR might still ask to know how long applicants took to fill out certain questions, and that information is not covered by any laws, as far as I know, so you may still have to provide it to them.

At the end of the day, however, it's your manager's job to decide what the company's business practices are going to be going forward. If you don't feel comfortable with their practices you may wish to start looking for a new job.

Answer (score 1):

"They do like to see whether the application was agonised over..."

Based on what?  How long the form was up?

It could also mean:

- Aunt Gladys called to tell them her puppy got a new collar.
- Little Timmy brought home his report card and wanted to show it to Daddy.
- Supper was eaten while the form was left up.
- A neighbor knocked on the door.
- A really good game was on television.

Also, geolocation data is pretty spotty.  Our company HQ's IP's come back to New York, but the office is in Grand Rapids, MI.

I'd fix this problem at the source:  By making HR realize what they think they're tracking isn't what they're looking at.  But again, this is HR.  Making bad decisions by taking dubious information out of context is what they (collectively) do best.

Answer (score 0):

These pieces of information can be had without user input beyond going to your website. So you can do whatever you want with them. Many sites routinely gather IP details for many different reasons.

The best way to make it clear to the user isn't by an obscure EULA somewhere, but just by displaying their IP address on the page.

Comment: That is a good idea, or at least in the confirmation so that they know.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong.  I write major apps for a very large company.  Gathering IP address is legal in every country.  How do I know?  Because I have had to go through Google Analytics regulatory training.

It would be illegal to try to gather user information and associate the user with the country but since the user is readily filling out the form you are 100% within your rights to attach that user to an IP address.  And once you have the IP address you can do whatever you like with it as long as you keep it to yourself.  Perfectly legal to turn IP into geotracking data (whether that is accurate or not) but you cannot sell this information or give it to 3rd parties.

Comment: The question isn't whether gathering an IP is legal... it's about whether HR using it when making hiring or interview decisions is legal.

Comment: @Catija - if gathering the data is legal, it is an assumption it would be used.  There is no law that says a person's country is an anonymous piece of data.  Are you telling me an employer doesn't have a right to know this?  In fact not only does an employer have a right, but it may be required as the country that they are physically in might have limitations or restrictions on certain countries and have limitations on % of staff that can be hired through another country.